# Using MDX, how to get only a few selected rows?

Tags: mdx, business-intelligence, pentaho

I have a `Color` dimension with **many colors**, but I want to show a table with just **two rows** (black and red). I tried this:

```
SELECT [Color].[black] || [Color].[red] ON ROWS, 
 {[Measures].defaultMember} ON COLUMNS 
from [SalesAnalysis]
```

The result I was expecting was a table with one column and two rows. One cell for black sales, one cell for red sales. An error comes instead.

**What MDX request** should I write?

*I also tried things called "aggregate" and "filter", but it seems that they are not what I am looking for.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have found:

```
SELECT {[Color].[black],[Color].[red]} ON ROWS, 
 {[Measures].defaultMember} ON COLUMNS 
from [SalesAnalysis]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try something like this:

```
SELECT {[Color]} ON ROWS, 
 {[Measures].defaultMember} ON COLUMNS 
FROM [SalesAnalysis]
WHERE {[Color].[black], [Color].[red]}
```